# Adding scripts within CartoDB infowindow?

Tags: carto, infowindow

i am trying to implement a simple "zoom to this point" link within a CartoDB infowindow. To do this i figure i need:

1. To be able to place a script within an infowindow (mustache) template, so that the zoom link can be dynamically set
2. Access to the lat/lng value that was clicked

Its not clear to me whether the JS should be placed within the mustache template (nested  tags seem a bit messy), or elsewhere - something like an "infowindow.complete" event would be ideal, but not sure if that exists.

Currently i have

```
<script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template2">
  <div class="cartodb-popup v2">
    <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
      <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
        <strong>Route {{content.data.routenumber}}</strong>
        <p>{{content.data.routename}}</p>
        <p><a href="" id="infowindow-zoom-link">Zoom in here</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#infowindow-zoom-link').click(function(e){
      // perform zoom based on lat/lng clicked
      // ...
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  </script>
</script>
```

My script does run, but i dont know how to access the lat/lng point. Is the information available within content.data? How can i debug what is in {{content}} ?

[This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122925/dynamic-content-in-infowindow) seems to provide an answer (ie use the 'featureClick' event, which has the lat/lng passed in), however the code doesn't fire for me - presumably because the content in the infowindow is not completed yet (hence my suggestion above)